# In gradle, how to access build profile properties in buildSrc from settings.gradle.kts?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In this tutorial, a mechanism was proposed to call functions under `buildSrc` directory in `build.gradle.kts` file:

(under `buildSrc`)

```kotlin
class Versions(properties: Map<String, *>) {
  // access properties here
}
```

(under `build.gradle.kts`)

```
val vs = Versions(project.properties)
```

When I try to do this in `settings.gradle.kts`, I got the following error:

```
val vs = Versions(settings.properties)

e: /home/peng/git/shapesafe/settings.gradle.kts:2:10: Unresolved reference: Versions
```

It appears that the classpath of buildSrc won't be visible to settings, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Why do you want to access data in `settings.gradle.kts`? Is this an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Good question: I have An includeBuild with a substitution rule in settings, which depends on a version property

Comment: What do you have at the moment? Can you share an example? What do you want to see in your `settings.gradle.kts`? Dependency substitution for included builds [don't require version numbers](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_build_declaring_substitutions), and I guess that's what in your `Versions` class, so I'm not clear what you're trying to do.